# Getting tml page output without HTML tags

Tags: tapestry

I am using Tapestry5.3. I have a dynamic web project (prject name: test) with test.tml and test.java.

Test.tml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd"
      xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">

<head>
</head>
<body>
${stringValue}
</body>
</html>
```

Test.java

```
public String getGenerateJson() {
return "welcome";
}
```

I have one more dynamic web project (project name: test2) with test2.tml and test2.java. Both projects are running into my tomcat server.

From test2.java, I make a http connetion to test.java for getting olny test.java return value (welcome) in test2.java.

Test2.java

```
final GetData data = new HttpGetData();
final String str = data.getContent("http://10.0.1.62:8080/Test/test");
System.out.println("String: " + str);
```

Output:

String:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/test/assets/1b4371c8cdb7af3/core/default.css"/><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/test/assets/1b4371c8cdb7af3/jquery/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.css"/><meta content="Apache Tapestry Framework (version 5.3.1)" name="generator"/></head><body>
welcome
</body></html>
```

But I got output like that.

Is chance to get only welcome from test.java. Please give me your valuable suggestion or idea to achieve like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to return a [StreamResponse](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3.7/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/StreamResponse.html) from your page's `onActivate` event. You won't need a template (.tml) to do this.

```
Object onActivate(EventContext context) {
   return new TextStreamResponse("text/plain", "welcome");
}
```

Since plain text isn't a great solution, you'll probably want to use [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) instead.

```
Object onActivate(EventContext context) {
   JSONObject json = new JSONObject("greeting", "welcome");
   return new TextStreamResponse("application/json", json.toCompactString());
}
```

For a simple way of creating restful webservices in tapestry, you might want to consider [tapestry-resteasy](http://tynamo.org/tapestry-resteasy+guide)